# Record based access control

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to implement a authorization system, that should work on permissions for each individual records. 
e.g. User U1 can Read a Record R1
User U2 can Edit/Delete Record R1

i.e. Each Record will have its own set of permitted users for Create/Read/Update/Delete. I dont want tot implement Role based system. 
Is there any rails gem/plugin to do that ?

Comment: I really dont mind to receive negative votes. But negative voters should at least take a minute to comment about whats wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Ryan Bates' CanCan [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). It also includes a helpful screencast.